# My StarCraft on wine 1.5.24 is on all workspaces

Tags: 12.04, wine, workspaces, playonlinux

I use PlayOnLinux and configured it to work on wine version 1.5.24.

The thing is the app is working on all workscapes, just like that
[image: sc2 on all workspaces]

So how that to work only on one?
It behaves just like any app that is on
"Always visible workspace"

I i change wine version, i must agian configure the wine, but it still behaves so.
The change whas about just after SC2 game whas updated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check if it isn't set to behave this way? You can check the right-click menu of the title bar.

Comment: It`s game through wine emulator, how should i find the title bar?

Comment: So the game is running in fullscreen? You can try holding Alt and right-clicking anywhere on the window, this should open the window menu.

Comment: Yes, and the game not allowing to work with Alt key. Intro screen and the game itself.

Answer (score 1):

Found a problem. Stupid simple.
This solved my issue:

- Go to PlayOnLinux
- pick an app and click on configure button
- pick a "Graphics" tab
- make sure that "Allow the window manager to...* checkboxes are selected

And than again click to play a game, now it is working on one workspace only. Yey!

Comment: Ah, of course. I didn't even think of that. It's usually on by default, because it's very unlikely a normal user would want it different.